# How to stream client webcam to web server in flash/rtmp

Tags: flash, nginx, stream, webcam, rtmp

I would like to stream client webcam data to an Nginx-rtmp server without the client having to use something like OBS. Is it possible to do this in their browser using flash? I would like to avoid webRTC if possible.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is quite simple, you can try this application which I built :

http://raspi.monaserver.ovh/MonaClients/VideoPublisher/

The source code is here : https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/tree/master/VideoPublisher

Otherwise there are plenty of other Flash applications on Internet.

You can also consider to use another media server, for example there are AMS, Wowza, MonaServer and Crtmpserver.

(I'm a developer of MonaServer which is an open source solution with RTMP, RTMFP, HTTP and Websocket support)

Regards

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the Janus WebRTC gateway server to capture client video and audio in the browser. I then forwarded the streams to an Nginx-RTMP server